# Windows 8.1 Bootcamp USB ports have power, but don't work

Tags: bootcamp, usb, sleep-wake, windows

I have (according to Apple) a "MACBOOK PRO (RETINA, 13-INCH, LATE 2013)". It has Windows 8.1 on itm installed via Bootcamp with the latest drivers from Apple Bootcamp Assistant on it. Possibly Intel display drivers have been updated via Windows Update, but I have no memory of any USB drivers being updated and it appears it is using "Intel USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 0100" (6.3.9600.17797).

When I use a USB 3.0 ethernet dongle or my portable hard drive for the first time after restarting the computer, they work fine. I can plug them in and out and they continue to work each time. After the computer lid has been closed (sleep) for awhile and it turns off the hard drive, and then I open it again, my USB devices are no longer recognized by Windows. The key here seems to be the hard drive turning off part. The USBs still have power running to them (e.g., the hard drive spins and still has a light on it), but there is zero evidence I can see of them being connected to my computer (e.g., the hard drive doesn't appear in My Computer and the dongle doesn't appear in USB or network devices at all).

Comment: idk how to fix it, but Windows probably doesn't know it slept, so doesn't know to reconnect. I presume you're talking about a Boot Camp Windows install, with the correct Apple drivers on it. If not...

Comment: yes, it is a bootcamp on it with the latest bootcamp drivers from apple.